# Handling PreferenceFragments over Ui Changes

Tags: java, android

I have a fragment containing a `FrameLayout`. And I load a `PreferenceFragment` into that `FrameLayout` if fragment is being created for the first time. The issue is when I change the orientation of the device the Fragments load in correctly but the `FrameLayout` doesn't show anything.

If I have to be more detailed then, the `PreferenceFragment` opens more `PreferenceFragments` with class name defined in the xml. And now say navigated a couple of preferences inside then, each time a Ui change occurs the `FrameLayout` firstly gets blank and further pops out the fragments in the backstack.

So what am I missing out? It would be really helpful if someone can explain the reason to me.

**Here's my code:**

```java
// BottomNavigationViewAdapter

public class MainNavigationAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    public MainNavigationAdapter(@NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
        super(fragmentActivity);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {

        switch (position) {

            case 0:
                return new FragmentA();
            case 1:
                return new FragmentB();
            case 2:
                return new MyProfileFragment();
            default:
                return null;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 3;
    }

}
```

```java
// MyProfileFragment

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mpf_frame_fl, new MainSettingsPreference()).commit();
    }

}
```

```xml
<!-- main_settings_preference.xml -->

<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Preference
        android:icon="@drawable/appearance"
        android:title="@string/appearance"
        app:fragment="com.xyz.abc.Settings.AppearanceFragment" />

    <Preference
        android:icon="@drawable/profile"
        android:title="@string/account_settings"
        app:fragment="com.xyz.abc.Settings.AccountSettingsPreference" />

    <Preference
        android:icon="@drawable/accessibility"
        android:key="ms_accessibility"
        android:title="@string/accessibility"
        app:fragment="com.xyz.abc.Settings.AccessibilityPreference" />

    <Preference
        android:icon="@drawable/privacy"
        android:key="ms_privacy"
        android:title="@string/privacy_settings"
        app:fragment="com.xyz.abc.Settings.SecurityPreference" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: Post your code.  Its hard to say what's going wrong without that.

Comment: I updated my question. Please see if you could help now @GabeSechan